# Onsen UI PostPush event callback fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, onsen-ui

I am working on an OnsenUI powered app.
It is having multiple pages.

I am using postpush event to fire my ajax requests for data.

Like below.

```
$scope.navi.on('postpush', function () {
//ajax code here
});
```

Now the issue is, my complete code looks like below.

```
$scope.navi.pushPage('linkone.html'); 
$scope.navi.on('postpush', function () {
//ajax 1
});

 $scope.navi.pushPage('linktwo.html'); 
$scope.navi.on('postpush', function () {
//ajax 2
});
```

If I navigate to linkone.html page it fires the ajax1.
After that if I navigate to linktwo.html it fires ajax1 and ajax2 both.

I want only relevant ajax to be fired. But both the events are getting fired. And if I keep on browsing pages, eventually too many requests starts getting fired.

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Probably the quickest work around is to set a boolean variable in the post event and check in the post event if it exists then not run your other code.

Answer (score 1):

What you are explaining is actually the expected behaviour. The `on` method adds a listener to be executed whenever the event becomes triggered. You seem to be adding more listeners without removing them.

**Alternatives**:

1. A simple alternative would be the `once` method which will be executed only once and then it will remove the listener automatically.
2. Instead of adding listeners you can just queue the ajax as a callback to the `pushPage` - either of these:

   ```
   $scope.navi.pushPage('linkone.html', {callback: ajax1});
   $scope.navi.pushPage('linkone.html').then(ajax1);
   ```

   should be fine.
3. You can add one listener which does different things depending on your page:

   ```
   $scope.navi.pushPage('linkone.html');
   $scope.navi.on('postpush', function(ev){
     if (ev.enterPage.id === 'page1') {
       ajax1();
     } else if (ev.enterPage.id === 'page2') {
       ajax2();
     }
   });
   ```

   The same thing can probably also be achieved with the page's `init` event.

   ```
   document.addEventListener('init', function(ev) {
     if (ev.target.id === 'page1') {
       ajax1();
     } else if (ev.target.id === 'page2') {
       ajax2();
     }
   });
   ```

   However do note that in this third alternative `page1` and `page2` must be the ids of the `ons-page` elements, **not** the templates'.